# Overviews for thematic raster maps

Tags: geoserver, thematic-map, gdaladdo

I have a landuse raster map with integer classes (1:agricultura, 2:pasture, etc). I'm trying to publish it through GeoServer and I'd like to use image overviews to speed things up. I tried gdaladdo with different resampling methods (nearest, average, cubic, mode) but the image looks too pixalated when not zoomed in. The best results I got were with the MODE option. Are there nay other options for working with overviews for thematic raster maps?